# Finding the nearest but higher value of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the most Pythonic way to find the key of the nearest but higher value from a given parameter.

For example, with

```
dict = {'a': 78.0, 'b': 87.0, 'c': 92.0},
```

The function

```
f(dict, 89.0)
```

would return

```
c
```

Comment: what if there are no higher values?

Comment: 87 and 92 are not equally distant from 89...

Comment: @drops: It looks like the intent is "nearest higher value", not "nearest value, breaking ties toward the higher value".

Comment: f(dict, 93.0) would return None, f(dict, 75.0) would return a, f(dict, 79.0) would return b. If this can help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
def f(dct, val):
    try:
        return min((v, k) for k, v in dct.items() if v >= val)[1]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 78.0, 'b': 87.0, 'c': 92.0}
>>> f(dct, 89)
'c'
>>> f(dct, 93)
>>> f(dct, 75)
'a'
>>> f(dct, 79)
'b'
```

If you are using Python >3.4 you can use the "default" keyword for the `min` builtin function:

```
def f(dct, val):
    return min(((v, k) for k, v in dct.items() if v >= val),
               default=(None, None))[1]
```